# Valgrind error on mem

Tags: php, c, linux

I am getting following error in valgrind, when i run my PHP application. I just need to find what is causing
    segmentation fault core dump error which halt my application.

```
==17131== Thread 36:
==17131== Invalid read of size 1
==17131==    at 0x4A08CE1: memcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:882)
==17131==    by 0x46574B: seek_to_tz_position (parse_tz.c:267)
==17131==    by 0x46587E: timelib_parse_tzfile (parse_tz.c:320)
==17131==    by 0x43E0CA: php_date_parse_tzfile (php_date.c:900)
==17131==    by 0x440CC3: get_timezone_info (php_date.c:975)
==17131==    by 0x443887: php_format_date (php_date.c:1228)
==17131==    by 0x44408E: php_date (php_date.c:1213)
==17131==    by 0x44411F: zif_date (php_date.c:1344)
==17131==    by 0x8E5411: zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (zend_vm_execute.h:550)
==17131==    by 0x8D55BA: execute_ex (zend_vm_execute.h:363)
==17131==    by 0x8479C8: zend_call_function (zend_execute_API.c:939)
==17131==    by 0x871290: zend_call_method (zend_interfaces.c:97)
==17131==  Address 0x1cb2e289 is 9 bytes inside a block of size 12 free'd
==17131==    at 0x4A063F0: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==17131==    by 0x3FC EC28 14: setlocale (in /lib64/libc-2.12.so)
==17131==    by 0x465765: seek_to_tz_position (parse_tz.c:269)
==17131==    by 0x46587E: timelib_parse_tzfile (parse_tz.c:320)
==17131==    by 0x43E0CA: php_date_parse_tzfile (php_date.c:900)
==17131==    by 0x440CC3: get_timezone_info (php_date.c:975)
==17131==    by 0x443887: php_format_date (php_date.c:1228)
==17131==    by 0x44408E: php_date (php_date.c:1213)
==17131==    by 0x44411F: zif_date (php_date.c:1344)
==17131==    by 0x8E5411: zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (zend_vm_execute.h:550)
==17131==    by 0x8D55BA: execute_ex (zend_vm_execute.h:363)
==17131==    by 0x8479C8: zend_call_function (zend_execute_API.c:939)
==17131==
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. But in the link there is no solution mention about my error.